# Insertion In php not working

Tags: php

I have this php script that inserts data from a form into the database.The code always returns an error. What might be the problem.
NB: the names of the fields in the form are correctly matched.

```
<?php 
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'townmanagement';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';

// Connect to server.
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)
or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

// Get values from form
$fname= mysql_escape_string(trim ($_POST['fname']));
$lastname= mysql_escape_string(trim ($_POST['lname']));
$dpt=mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['dpt']));
$user= mysql_escape_string(trim ($_POST['username']));
$psswd=mysql_escape_string(trim ($_POST['password']));



// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO staff_reg (fname, lname, dpt, username, password, registration_date)
VALUES ($fname, $lastname, $dpt, $user, SHA1($password), NOW())";
$result = mysql_query($sql); 

if($result){
echo ("sUCCESSFUL");
}
else {
echo "error";;
}

?>

<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: "The code always returns an error. " - well...what's the error?

Comment: I would bet it's a BSOD, @slugonamission.

Comment: where the error is throwed ?

Comment: ...and please do not use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated.    BTW: What' s the error message.

Comment: It looks like the error is "error" :P

Comment: -0.49 for using mysql in 2013.  Try [mysqli](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: @Gareh yeah.its that error that is echoed

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote your parameters in the SQL statement

```
  $sql="INSERT INTO staff_reg (fname, lname, dpt, username, password, registration_date)
VALUES ('$fname', '$lastname', '$dpt', '$user', SHA1('$password'), NOW())";
```

And if possible you should upgrade to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: 'if($result){
echo ("sUCCESSFUL");
}
else {
echo "error";;
}'

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotes around your values:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO staff_reg (fname, lname, dpt, username, password, registration_date)
VALUES ('$fname', '$lastname', '$dpt', '$user', SHA1($password), NOW())";
```

For better troubleshooting, consider adding to your `mysql_query` statement to detect when and why the query fails:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );
```

Finally, be aware that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Please consider updating your code to use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_select_db($db_database,$db_server)
or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());
//you have to select db using connection previously established
```

Comment: @php nothing is shown again.nothing happens and the data is not saved as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You should know, that I am not encouraging you to use `mysql_` since it is deprecated, and you should learn and implement PDO in the future:

```
<?php 
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'townmanagement';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';

// Connect to server.
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)
or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

// Get values from form
$fname= mysql_escape_string(trim ($_POST['fname']));
$lastname= mysql_escape_string(trim ($_POST['lname']));
$dpt=mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['dpt']));
$user= mysql_escape_string(trim ($_POST['username']));
$psswd=mysql_escape_string(trim ($_POST['password']));

$psswd2 = SHA1($psswd);

// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO staff_reg (fname, lname, dpt, username, password, registration_date)
VALUES ('".$fname."', '".$lastname."', '".$dpt."', '".$user."', '".$psswd2."', "NOW()" )";

if(mysql_query($sql)); {
echo ("sUCCESSFUL");
}else {
echo "error";;
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: @kkStep No problem. Don't forget to accept any of the answers that helped you, so your question can be marked as answered